# Javafx getting the new value of a cell that is changed in a tableview

Tags: javafx, tableview

I've made an editable cell in my javafx table using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE, but whatever I try I cannot get the new value. Instead I always get the value in the first column using

> ```
> firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
>         (CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) -> {
>             ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
>                     t.getTablePosition().getRow())
>                     ).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
>     });
> ```

(The code example in the link above)

My code is large, its my project but roughly my code so far for this section is.

```
  timeColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
  timeColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent event) {
        tableView.getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow());
     }
  });
```

I am editing a cell in row 1, column 2 but for some reason it is always returning the object in row 1 column 1 and not the new value in row 1 column 2.

Any advice?

I've event tried 
`tableView.getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()) + 1;`

But this did not work

Comment: `tableView.getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())` (or equivalently, `event.getRowValue()`) gives the value represented by the whole row, not the cell. The new value is just `event.getNewValue()`. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: event.getNewValue() worked. Thank you

Comment: How would I grab the object in the column left of my cell?

Comment: `event.getRowValue().getXXX()` where `XXX` is the property in the column you want...

Comment: I mean, If currently my new value is in row 1 column 2. How would I grab the object it's associated to aswell (row 1 column 1)

Comment: I understood the question. You have some property associated with each column via `column.setCellValueFactory(...)`. You do `event.getRowValue().getXXX()` where `XXX` is the property associated with the column.

Comment: @James_D (sry for intruding, doing some research on expection/doc/usage [around edit events](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8273285)) - _or equivalently, event.getRowValue()_ that's the question: really the current value or the value at the time of creating the event? The equivalent methods in Tree/TableColumn are doc'ed (or at least implemented) to be those at the time of instantiation. On the event it sounds unclear (for me)

Comment: @kleopatra In typical usage, the row value for a table is going to be a mutable object, and `getRowValue()` is going to return a reference to it. (The docs say it's returning a value from the table's `items` list.) So querying properties on that is going to give you the current value.  So I think what you're asking is whether the property belonging to the item has been changed at that time; surely in `onEditCommit()` it will have been changed (committed). Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @James_D no misunderstanding on your part, just muddied thinking on my :) My problem is that the event is implemented in a way that `getOldValue()` is mutable (which is wrong, IMO), its value depends on whether or not a handler notified before mine already committed the newValue (in which case `getOldValue == getNewValue`).

Comment: I plan to change the impl of `getOldValue` to make it immutable. Should that mean changing `getRowValue` (to return the value at instantiation, like `position.getItem()`) as well? Your answer is: no? If a handler replaces the row, the next handler will see that new row with no relation to the old value ... hmm, would it matter? Just thinking loud, sry ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get the correct person.

```
TableView tempTable = (TableView)event.getTableView();
Person tempPerson = (Person)tempTable.getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow());
tempPerson.setYourMethod(event.getNewValue());//maybe toString?
```

If your object is not a Person object, then replace Person with your object type.

Comment: I don't understand why when im priting what im returning give the object I want, by printing "classes.StopPoint@1606348", but I can't use the methods of the object.

I accessed it by System.out.println(tableView.getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()));

Comment: You have to cast the object to your object type.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @James_D comment above. If you want to get the first column's value then just do

```
column2.setOnEditCommit( e -> {
    //here you can get the value of column1 corresponding to column2
    System.out.println(e.getRowValue().getColumn1());
});
```